# scss file is not in the source map - webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, source-maps, webpack-style-loader

I have a webpack config which serves minified js and css after compiling them using the babel. I use scss and then convert them using sass, postcss, css loader.
For no reason I am getting this error.

```
ERROR in C:/Development/cxd-addon-iss/digital-spearhead/digital-ui/src/~/css-loader?{"minimize":true,"sourceMap":true}!C:/Development/cxd-addon-iss/digital-spearhead/digital-ui/src/~/postcss-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!C:/Development/cxd-addon-iss/digital-spearhead/digital-ui/src/~/sass-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!../scss/core.scss
    Module build failed: Error: "../../../../../../../node_modules/@tr-ui/cxd-ui/lib/styles/base/_config.scss" is not in the SourceMap.
```

My web pack config is below:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

// Plugins
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const SpritePlugin = require('svg-sprite-loader/plugin');
const AutoPrefixer = require('autoprefixer');

// Env
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const isProduction = nodeEnv === 'production';

// Dirs
const jsSourcePath = path.join(__dirname, './main/content/jcr_root/etc/designs/digital/clientlibs/src/js');
const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, './main/content/jcr_root/etc/designs/digital/clientlibs/dist');
const sourcePath = path.join(__dirname, './main/content/jcr_root/etc/designs/digital/clientlibs/src');

// https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56
process.noDeprecation = true;


const plugins = [
  new SpritePlugin(),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv),
    },
  }),
  new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
  new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
    options: {
      postcss: [
        AutoPrefixer({
          browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ios 8', 'ie 9', 'ie 10', 'ie 11'],
        }),
      ],
      context: sourcePath,
    },
  }),
];


const rules = [
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/i,
    exclude: /(node_modules|cxdigital-ui-library)/,
    use: [
      'babel-loader',
      'eslint-loader',
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.svg$/i,
    include: /node_modules\/@tr-ui\/cxd-ui\/lib\/assets\/icons/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
        options: {
          extract: true,
          spriteFilename: 'assets/icons/sprite.svg',
        },
      },
      'svgo-loader',
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i,
    //include: /node_modules\/@tr-ui\/cxd-ui\/lib\/assets\/img/,
    loaders: [
      'url-loader?limit=1&name=assets/img/[name].[ext]',
      {
        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
        query: {
          mozjpeg: { quality: [90, 95], progressive: true },
          gifsicle: { interlaced: true },
          optipng: { optimizationLevel: 5 },
          pngquant: { quality: '75-90', speed: 3 },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|svg)$/i,
    //include: /node_modules\/@tr-ui\/cxd-ui\/lib\/assets\/favicon/,
    loaders: [
      'url-loader?limit=1&name=assets/favicon/[name].[ext]',
      {
        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
        query: {
          optipng: { optimizationLevel: 5 },
          pngquant: { quality: '75-90', speed: 3 },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(ico)$/i,
    loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/favicon/[name].[ext]',
  },
  {
    test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/i,
    loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]',
  },
];


if (isProduction) {
  plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        screw_ie8: true,
        conditionals: true,
        unused: true,
        comparisons: true,
        sequences: true,
        dead_code: true,
        evaluate: true,
        if_return: true,
        join_vars: true,
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
      },
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('css/styles.css'),
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      include: /\.(css|js)$/i,
      banner: '[file]\nCopyright (c) Varun',
    })
  );

  rules.push(
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: [
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: true } },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader' },
          { loader: 'sass-loader' },
        ],
      }),
    }
  );
} else {
  console.log('_______________________ ****************** ________________________')
  console.log(' **** this is not a production - this is a development platform ***')
  console.log('_______________________ ****************** ________________________')
  plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        screw_ie8: true,
        conditionals: true,
        unused: true,
        comparisons: true,
        sequences: true,
        dead_code: true,
        evaluate: true,
        if_return: true,
        join_vars: true,
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
      },
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('css/styles.css'),
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      include: /\.(css|js)$/i,
      banner: '[file]\nCopyright (c) Varun',
    })
  );

  rules.push(
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: 'css-loader?sourceMap!postcss-loader!sass-loader?sourceMap',
      }),
    }
  );
}


module.exports = {
  devtool: isProduction ? false : 'source-map',
  context: jsSourcePath,
  entry: {
    js: 'index.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: buildPath,
    publicPath: '/etc/designs/digital/clientlibs/dist/',
    filename: 'js/app.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    symlinks: false,
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
      jsSourcePath,
    ],
  },
  plugins
};
```

I have also tried a lot of options like adding options to the sass, postcss loader and then gave a sourcemap as true. Cannot get this working since the source map is failing to find those files.

Is there a way to do this with sourcemap.
I need this source map for debugging the code

Comment: you probably need to set sourcemap true for all the loaders looking for scss changes. Also, upgrade your webpack configuration. It will look much cleaner

Comment: I have already tried that option as well

loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: [
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: true, sourceMap:true } },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader', options:{sourceMap:true} },
          { loader: 'sass-loader', options{sourceMap:true} },
        ],
      }),